# Correlation between properties

Tags: correlation

I have a table in a database where each record includes the ID of a person and the ID of a property of that person. Each person may have more than one property.
Which is the statistical instrument that let me measure the correlation between two properties?

E.g., Assume that we have the following DB table

```
IDPerson     IDProperty
Pluto        dog
Pluto        disney
DonaldDuck   duck
DonaldDuck   disney
Huey         duck
Huey         disney
Dewey        duck
Louie        disney
Louie        duck
```

I see a correlation between "disney" and "duck".

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you!

Comment: @Stijn Hi! I think that in my case (2x2 table of random variables) I can recurr to the [Phi coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient).